# how to create image viwer in matlab dynamically?

Tags: image, user-interface, matlab

I have many images to display and do paint on them. I want to use axes objects in the matlab gui for individual images which should off course be scrollable. I dont know that how to create axes objects for individual images programmatically. Second is that I wanna create only one callback for all of them. I am wondering if someone can really help or point to some link as I did not find any good information.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be a helpful start : [Plotting Dynamic MRI Slice Images in MATLAB](http://alenblog.wordpress.com/2010/09/14/plot-dynamic-mri-slice-images/)